# Error when I try to export adhoc with bitcode

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, bitcode

I get this error when I do adhoc export from xcode after I have archived the project:

An error occurred during export

`Failed to verify bitcode in Someframework.framework/Someframework
Cannot extract bundle from /var/folders/rg/8ydk5h297ng50z_3dpkr5jx00000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.5rb/Root/Payload/...`

But when I export for the appstore it completes as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding the magic compilation flags:

BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE bitcode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your framework build only for device. Please stripe out simulator architecture before exporting framework build.

If you are creating build using Jekins following script might work for you

```
if [ -d  ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework ] && lipo ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework/YOURFramework.framework -verify_arch x86_64; then
lipo -remove i386 ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework/YOURFramework.framework -output ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework/YOURFramework.framework
lipo -remove x86_64 ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework/YOURFramework.framework -output ./${BUILD_DIR}/YOURFramework.framework/YOURFramework.framework
```